# Parallel Period retuning the wrong values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a fact table with sales data, and I need to calculate the % change month over month. I have tried the following formula:

```
PreviousMonthSales:= calculate(
                        SUM('fTable'[Sales];
                        Parallelperiod( 'Calender'[Date], -1, month)
                      )
```

The result that I receive in the pivot table is the same value as the current month. So it seems like something is being calculated, but the result is not different at all from the regular sales column.

The Calender Table is my date table. I have also tried using the functions PreviousMonth and DateAdd,  but that has also not worked.

I am not sure if it will make a difference, but I am using Power Pivot in Excel 365, not Power BI.

Comment: I created a calculated column to see if the parallel period is correct or not. I used this formula: ParallelPeriod =  parallelperiod('Sales'[Date],-1,Month). The calculated column was correct, the parallel period is always 1 month after the current month.

Comment: Have you set your calendar table as a date table?